# How to POST a table to PHP and save it as a text file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table

I have the following program for a form data.
I have text boxes to input values. after I input those when I click 'Submit' it should display the input values below and the text box should get reset. I can enter another set of inputs and can submit it. It should display below the previous one. 
Now here's the actual problem I am facing. There is a save button. When I click it, the table input should be saved into my PC using PHP.. But it is not working. Instead of saving the file, it adds another row below..

Below is my html and PHP codes. Please help..!

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Form download</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<style>
.results {
    width: 600px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form"  method="POST" action="excel.php" > 
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:left">Option 1</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text" name="option1" size="20"></td>

      <td style="text-align:left">Option 2</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="text" name="option2" size="20"></td>
     </tr>

      </table>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="save" >
  <div class="buttonHolder">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onClick="insertData()" id="btn_s" />
        <input value="reset" type="reset" id="btn_i" /> 
    </div>

</form> 
    <script>

$(function insertData() {
  $('form[name="form"]').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

         var name  = $('input[name="option1"]').val(),
         sName = $('input[name="option2"]').val();

       $('body').append('<table class="results">'
                          +'<tr>'
                            +'<th>Option 1</th>'
                            +'<th>Option 2</th>'

                          +'</tr>'
                          +'<tr>' 
                            +'<td>'+name+'</td>'
                            +'<td>'+sName+'</td>'
                               +'</tr>'

                    + '</table>');
  // $('input[type="reset"]').click(function() {
    //  ($('#text').val()).remove(); 
   });
     });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
 <?php

$myfile = fopen("newFile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt= 'Option 1 ' ."\t" .'Option 2 ' ."\r\n" 
 .$_POST['option1'] ."\t"  .$_POST['option2']."\r\n" 
.$_POST['option3'] ."\t" .$_POST['option4'] ."\r\n".$_POST['option5'] ."\t" .$_POST['option6'] ."\r\n"  ;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Please help.. I am stuck with this for 2 days..

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier like this:

```
$header = "Option 1 \t  Option 2\n";  
file_put_contents("newFile.txt", $header, FILE_APPEND );
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  file_put_contents("newFile.txt", $value."\n", FILE_APPEND );
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. but I think there is a problem with html part also.. when I click the save button it should process the php part ryt? but instead it does the part of 'submit ' button..! :(

Answer (score 0):

In HTML you need to change type of 'Submit' button from submit to button. And change your script to -

```
$(function insertData() {
     $('#btn_s').on('click', function(e) {

     var name  = $('input[name="option1"]').val(),
     sName = $('input[name="option2"]').val();

   $('body').append('<table class="results">'
                      +'<tr>'
                        +'<th>Option 1</th>'
                        +'<th>Option 2</th>'

                      +'</tr>'
                      +'<tr>' 
                        +'<td>'+name+'</td>'
                        +'<td>'+sName+'</td>'
                           +'</tr>'

                + '</table>');
   // $('input[type="reset"]').click(function() {
   //  ($('#text').val()).remove(); 
   });
 });
```

Comment: I tried. but now when I click  submit it directs to the php. The table is not displaying below now.